# Return sequence of changes to get from one string to another

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I want to build an algorithm that returns the shortest sequence of changes that will transform one three-digit string to another three-digit string. The intermediate words is limited to a pre-defined array of Strings.

For example, I have inputs `start = ABC`, `end = DEF`, and `words[] = {ABC, XZZ, AEC, DEF, AEF}`. The algorithm should return `{ABC, AEC, AEF, DEF}`. For each step in the transformation, only one letter can change, and the intermediate words must all be elements of `words[]`. If such a transformation is not possible, I would return `null`. If `start` and `end` are the same, then I would return an empty list.

I've been thinking about this for a while now and I considered for each step, checking through all the elements in `words[]` to find one that differed from the current element by one and proceeding that way, but I'm unsure how to formulate this into code. Could I possibly use a TrieMap?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service , please paste your attempts here

Comment: You can solve this with a special trie where for each word in the dictionary you add every permutation with `*` substituted for one character. This helps you find edges between words that differ only in one character.